# quaternion with symbolic variable

Tags: matlab

Is Matlab capable of handling quaternion with symbolic variables? There is no information in the documentation.  The following script is not working

```
syms a
d=quaternion(1,2,3,a)
```

This is the actual error

```
All inputs to the quaternion constructor must be the same class (double or
single).
```

Comment: I don't have the appropriate toolbox, so I can't test this, but I would try the following. `a=sym('a',[4,1]);` `d=quaternion(a(1),a(2),a(3),a(4));`

Comment: @BenGrossmann not working.

Comment: What error do you get when you try it?

Comment: @BenGrossmann same error.

Comment: One workaround that you might want to consider is using the [complex matrix representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Matrix_representations) of quaternions.

Comment: What do you intend to do with these symbolic quaternions downstream in your code? It wouldn't be too hard to write your own basic functions such as add, subtract, multiply, conjugate, and inverse.

Comment: @JamesTursa I'm implementing my own class so I can eventually implement dual quaternion class for robot modelling such as forward kinematics and Jacobian matrix.

Answer (score 0):

If the built-in `quaternion` objects supports `sym` types then try the array constructor

```
syms a
q = quaternion([1,2,3,a])
```

or

```
q = quaternion(str2sym('[1,2,3,a]'))
```

If MATLAB does not have an array constructor then you have do manually assign each value

```
v = str2sym('[1,2,3,a]');
q = quaternion(v(1),v(2),v(3),v(4))
```

Comment: None works.....

Comment: You might have to roll your own quaternion class to support symbolic math.

Comment: Sadly this is what I'm doing.

Comment: I made [a reference sheet](https://ja72.github.io/quaternions.pdf) for quaternions since I have programmed them in many different environments.

Comment: that's a hell of work. Thanks.

Comment: Mathworks is getting lazy lately. :<

Comment: The issue is that quaternion is part of the aerospace toolbox, and they should have implemented it in the general module since it has applications beyond aerospace. Also making it work with symbolic toolbox I guess wasn't a priority.

Comment: Their applications are even more in Robotics and their Robotics Toolbox is lacking such functionalities. May be it is the time to learn Mathematica.

Comment: I have been trying to find a symbolic environment for robotics for years now. Anything that would do vector algebra (product identities and expansions) symbolically. Like **a** × **b** + **b** × **a** = **0**  Most symbolic packages do vectors by components only and you end up doing a lot of simplifications by hand before coding anything.

Comment: Need to be careful when mixing quaternion functionality in MATLAB. The Aerospace Toolbox uses right-chain convention, the Robotics Toolbox uses left-chain convention (conjugate of right-chain), and the quaternion( ) class uses both conventions with the 'point' and 'frame' options. You can easily get into trouble with wrong results if you mix these incorrectly.

Comment: @JamesTursa - great point. And shame on MathWorks for not being consistent.

Comment: It seems there is no support for this functionality sadly. I've implemented my own and solved the forward kinematic problem I'm working on. Thank you.